# Zip function in System F

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory, system-f

Let's define list type

```
list = forall 'a, 'x. ('a -> 'x -> 'x) -> 'x -> 'x
```

where for instance

```
nil = Λ'a . Λ'x . λ(c : 'a -> 'x -> 'x) . λ(e : 'x) . e
cons = Λ'a . Λ'x . λ(head : 'a) . λ(tail : list 'a 'x) . λ(c : 'a -> 'x -> 'x) . λ(e : 'x) . c head (tail c e)
```

I am trying to define function `zip` of type

```
zip : forall 'a, 'b, 'c, 'x. ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> list 'a 'x -> list 'b 'x -> list 'c 'x
```

That intuitively does

```
zip (+) [1,2,3] [4,5,6] = [5,7,9]
zip (λa . λb . a) [1,2] [2,3,4] = [1,2]
zip (λa . λb . a) [2,3,4] [1,2] = [2,3]
```

Note that it truncates the longer list to fit the shorter.

The main problem I encounter here is that I cannot "iterate" over two lists at once. How can implement such a function in system F? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to write solution for it. First of all let's define helper `option` type:

```
option = forall 'a, 'x. ('a -> 'x) -> 'x -> 'x
```

Which has two constructors:

```
none = Λ'a . Λ'x . λ (onsome : 'a -> 'x) . λ (onnone : 'x) . onnone
some = Λ'a . Λ'x . λ (elem : 'a) . λ (onsome : 'a -> 'x) . λ (onnone : 'x) . onsome elem
```

Next step are functions that will extract `head` and `tail` of the list. `head` will return `option 'elemtype` to handle empty list case, but `tail` will just return empty list on empty list (in similar manner to predecessor function on Church numerals)

```
head = Λ 'a . λ (l : list 'a) . l (λ (elem : 'a) . λ (p : option 'a) . some elem) none
tail = Λ 'a . λ (l : list 'a) .
    pair_first 
       ( l (λ (elem : 'a) . λ (p : pair (list 'a) (list 'a)) .
               make_pair (list 'a) (list 'a) 
                  (pair_second (list 'a) (list 'a) p) 
                  (cons 'a elem (pair_second (list 'a) (list 'a) p))) 
           (make_pair (list 'a) (list 'a) (nil 'a) (nil 'a)))
```

The idea of `head` is that we start aggregating our list starting with `none` on empty list and for each new element from the left we set this element as our result wrapped by `some` to preserve typing.
`tail` on the other hand does not need `option` to be well defined, because in case of empty list we may just return an empty list. It looks very ugly, but uses same technique as predecessor of natural numbers. I assume `pair` interface is known.

Next, let's define `listmatch` function that will pattern match on given list

```
listmatch = Λ 'a . Λ 'x . λ (l : list 'a) . λ (oncons : 'a -> list 'a -> 'x) . λ (onnil : 'x) .
    (head 'a l)
      (λ (hd : 'a) . oncons hd (tail 'a l))
      onnil
```

This function helps us distinguish empty list and non-empty list and perform some actions after its destruction.

Almost finally, we would like to have `foldl2` function that given function `f`, empty case `em` and two lists `[a,b,c]` and `[x,y]` returns something like this: `f(f(em a x) b y)` (shrinks lists to the shorter one cutting off the tail).

It can be defined as

```
foldl2 =
  Λ 'a . Λ 'b . Λ 'c .
  λ (f : 'c -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c) . λ (em : 'c) . λ (la : list 'a) . λ (lb : list 'b) .
  pair_first 'c (list 'b)
    ((reverse 'a la)
      ( λ (el : 'a) . λ (p : pair 'c (list 'b)) . 
        listmatch 'a (pair 'c (list 'b)) (pair_second 'c (list 'b) p)
          (λ (hd : 'a) . λ (tl : list 'a) .
            make_pair 'c (list 'b) 
              (f (pair_first 'c (list 'b) p) el hd)
              tl)
          (make_pair 'c (list 'b) (pair_first 'c (list 'b) p) (nil 'a))
      )
      (make_pair 'c (list 'b) em lb))
```

After this the `zip` is just in our hands:

```
zip = 
  Λ 'a . Λ 'b . Λ 'c .
  λ (f : 'a -> 'b -> 'c) . λ (la : list 'a) . λ (lb : list 'b) .
  reverse 'c
    (foldl2 'a 'b 'c
      (λ (lt : 'c) . λ (a : 'a) . λ (b : 'b) . cons 'c (f a b) lt)
      (nil 'c) la lb)
```

Comment: how do you run this program?

Comment: This is not an actual programming language, but rather a notation of pure lambda calculus with F system. It can be however rewritten to some language that supports type applications and higher rank types such as Agda, Idris, Coq or maybe Haskell. Also, you may perform manual beta reduction if you want to stick to the roots

Comment: Technically, System F is, and can be used as, an actual programming language. It's just not very ergonomic. I have a written an intrepeter in which you can directly program using System F

Comment: @crunch can you post a link?

Comment: @radrow https://github.com/lazear/types-and-programming-languages - It is close to being a port of Benjamin Pierce's typecheckers from the book Types and Programming Languages